# Semaphore in Java. producer-consumer problem printer

Tags: java, multithreading

```
package producerconsumer;
 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public  class Buffer {
    int t;
    private final Semaphore notEmptyy  = new Semaphore(0); // prevent underflow
      private final Semaphore notFulll = new Semaphore(10); // prevent overflow
   private int itemn;
    private int itemb;
     int count=0;
     int buffersize =10 ;
    private final  BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(buffersize); 
    private final Semaphore mutex  = new Semaphore(1); // control buffer access
    private final Semaphore notEmpty  = new Semaphore(0); // prevent underflow
      private final Semaphore notFull = new Semaphore(10); // prevent overflow
    
          
    

     
    public    Buffer(){
          
    }
 public   void add( int x) throws InterruptedException{
 while(count== buffersize )  
     notFulll.acquire();
 System.out.println("user printer-request,: " +Thread.currentThread().getName() + "  " + x); 
  queue.offer(x);
     count++;
  notEmptyy.release();


 }   
    public int take() throws InterruptedException{
        
        while(queue.isEmpty())  
     notEmptyy.acquire();
    t=queue.take();
     count--;
  notFulll.release();
  return t; 

    }
    
 
       public   void put( ){    
while(true){
       try  {
           Random random = new Random();
            int data = random.nextInt(100);
        notFull .acquire();
        mutex .acquire();
         add(data);
          mutex .release();
           notEmpty .release();
        //   itemb = data;
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("InterruptedException caught ");
      }   
    //  System.out.println("user printer-request,: " +Thread.currentThread().getName() + "  " + itemb); 
    //   this.item = item; 
      
    }
}
       

    public void  get(){
     while(true){ 
      try{
          notEmpty .acquire();
          mutex .acquire();
            itemn = take();
           mutex .release();
           notFull .release();
           queue.remove(itemn);
            System.out.println("print request, : "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" " + itemn );
      } catch (InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("InterruptedException caught ");
      } 
     
     
    }   
   } 
}
```

```
package producerconsumer;


 
 
public class producers implements Runnable{
    private static final int DELAY = 500;
    private Buffer osLabGroup;
public producers(Buffer buffer){
        osLabGroup = buffer;
    }
 

    
    public void run(){
  //    while(true){
           
        osLabGroup.put();
        try{
            
            Thread.sleep(DELAY);
        }catch (InterruptedException exception) {}
    }
}
```

```
package producerconsumer;


public class consumers implements Runnable{
    private static final int DELAY = 1000;
    private Buffer osLabGroup;
public consumers(Buffer buffer){
        osLabGroup = buffer;
    }

    
    public void run(){
      //  while(true){
        osLabGroup.get();
        try{
           
            Thread.sleep(DELAY);
        }catch (InterruptedException exception) {}
    }
}
//}
```

```
package producerconsumer;

public class ProducerConsumer {

  
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        
   Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
      
            producers p1 = new producers(buffer);
            consumers c1 = new consumers(buffer);
             producers p2 = new producers(buffer);
            consumers c2 = new consumers(buffer);
             producers p3 = new producers(buffer);
            consumers c3 = new consumers(buffer);
            Thread pr1 = new Thread(p1);
            Thread co1 = new Thread(c1);
            Thread pr2 = new Thread(p2);
            Thread co2 = new Thread(c2);
            Thread pr3 = new Thread(p3);
            Thread co3 = new Thread(c3);
             pr1.setName("p1");
              co1.setName("c1");
               pr2.setName("p2");
                co2.setName("c2");
                 pr3.setName("p3");
                  co3.setName("c3");
                   
            pr1.start();
            co1.start(); 
            pr2.start();
            co2.start();
            pr3.start();
            co3.start();
        }
    }
```

I have a program that simulates the print jobs of a printer, one job at a time: either from Producer or Consumer and it shares an object called a *Buffer*.

in the buffer it has Set1 of threads, producers, put data with a ½ second delay.

also it does have a Set2 of threads, consumers, read data from the buffer with one second delay.

as it stands, I am trying to follow this guy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxw2y27z0V4&t=1207s

using semaphore this is my code
I problem my output is not accurate [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62mfZ.png)

this my edited code

```
package producerconsumer;
 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public  class Buffer {
    int t;
    private final Semaphore notEmptyy  = new Semaphore(0); // prevent underflow
      private final Semaphore notFulll = new Semaphore(10); // prevent overflow
   private int itemn;
    private int itemb;
     int count=0;
     int buffersize =10 ;
     private final  ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(buffersize); 
    private final  LinkedList<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>(list); 
    private final Semaphore mutex  = new Semaphore(1); // control buffer access
    private final Semaphore notEmpty  = new Semaphore(0); // prevent underflow
      private final Semaphore notFull = new Semaphore(10); // prevent overflow
    
          
    

     
    public    Buffer(){
          
    }
 public   void add( int x) throws InterruptedException{
 while(count== buffersize )  
     notFulll.acquire();
 System.out.println("user printer-request,: " +Thread.currentThread().getName() + "  " + x); 
  queue.offer(x);
     count++;
  notEmptyy.release();


 }   
    public   int take() throws InterruptedException{
        
        while(count ==0)  
     notEmptyy.acquire();
    t=queue.pollFirst();
     count--;
  notFulll.release();
  return t; 

    }
    
 
       public   void put( ){    
while(true){
       try  {
           Random random = new Random();
            int data = random.nextInt(100);
        notFull.acquire();
        mutex.acquire();
         add(data);
          mutex.release();
           notEmpty.release();
        //   itemb = data;
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("InterruptedException caught ");
      }   
    //  System.out.println("user printer-request,: " +Thread.currentThread().getName() + "  " + itemb); 
    //   this.item = item; 
      
    }
}
       

    public   void  get(){
     while(true){ 
      try{
          notEmpty.acquire();
          mutex.acquire();
            itemn = take();
           mutex.release();
           notFull.release();
         // queue.remove(itemn);
            System.out.println("print request, : "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" " + itemn );
      } catch (InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("InterruptedException caught ");
      } 
     
     
    }   
   } 
}
```

i get this output [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM37D.png)
and this output [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVmXa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Buffer#get`, when you take an item from queue, you call `queue#remove` again. This is a wrong behavior. You should consume this item instead of operating the queue outside of the concurrency control code. This can lead to abnormal behaviors, such as deadlock.

```
try {
    notEmpty .acquire();
    mutex .acquire();
    itemn = take();
    mutex .release();
    notFull .release();
    // why remove from queue again? It is already taken from queue. Comment this line
    // queue.remove(itemn);
    System.out.println("print request, : "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" " + itemn );
} catch (InterruptedException e){
    System.out.println("InterruptedException caught ");
}
```

In addition, in your program, you should replace `ArrayBlockingQueue` with a collection class under `java.util` package, such as `LinkedList`.

[ArrayBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) you use is actually a thread-safe `blocking queue`. You can directly use `take&put` to complete this program without other concurrency control.

**EDIT**:

As mentioned in the video introduction, there are two ways to solve the producer-consumer problem, semaphore or monitor. Your code seems to mix these two together. There is no need to do any concurrency control in your `add` and `take` method.

Code should be:

```
public class consumers implements Runnable{
    private static final int DELAY = 1000;
    private Buffer osLabGroup;
    public consumers(Buffer buffer){
        osLabGroup = buffer;
    }

    public void run(){
        while (true) {
            osLabGroup.get();
            try{
                Thread.sleep(DELAY);
            }catch (InterruptedException exception) {}
        }
    }
}

public class producers implements Runnable{
    private static final int DELAY = 500;
    private Buffer osLabGroup;
    public producers(Buffer buffer){
        osLabGroup = buffer;
    }
    public void run(){
           while(true) {
               osLabGroup.put();
               try {
                   Thread.sleep(DELAY);
               } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
               }
           }
    }
}

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public  class Buffer {
    int buffersize =10 ;
    private final  LinkedList<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    private final Semaphore mutex  = new Semaphore(1); // control buffer access
    private final Semaphore notEmpty  = new Semaphore(0); // prevent underflow
    private final Semaphore notFull = new Semaphore(buffersize); // prevent overflow

    public Buffer(){
    }
    public void add( int x) throws InterruptedException{
        System.out.println("user printer-request,: " +Thread.currentThread().getName() + "  " + x + "," + System.currentTimeMillis());
        queue.add(x);
    }
    public int take() throws InterruptedException{
        Integer first = queue.removeFirst();
        System.out.println("print request, : "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" " + first + "," + System.currentTimeMillis() );
        return first;
    }

    public  void put(){
        try  {
            Random random = new Random();
            int data = random.nextInt(100);
            notFull.acquire();
            mutex.acquire();
            add(data);
            mutex.release();
            notEmpty.release();
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("InterruptedException caught ");
        }
    }

    public void  get(){
        try{
            notEmpty.acquire();
            mutex.acquire();
            int take = take();
            mutex.release();
            notFull.release();
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("InterruptedException caught ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not look at your code carefully, there are many other problems with the code. Updated the answer...